# How to navigate to next page after showing UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipageviewcontroller

Trying to show a Guide Page with UIPageViewController and last page has a button to start app.
Added IBAction to move to next page but it doesn't work.

I want to make move to another page when user clicked a button in the last page of UIPageViewController.

```
    @IBAction func btnStart(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let main = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainBoard")

        main.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(main, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is my button action code and it doesn't work.
I added it in UIPageViewController code.

Comment: What happens when you tap the button? What does “make move to another page” mean?

Comment: nothing happens when click the button. I want to show another view and finish UIPageVIewCOntroller when it clicked

Comment: What does debugging show? When you tap the button, is `btnStart` called? Why _would_ `btnStart` be called? Is there a button in the storyboard hooked to the action?